# Doxygen called from scons fails on Win32 platform as unfound

Tags: doxygen, scons

I have a problem with a Doxygen target in a scons build I'm working on.  In particular, the doxygen application appears not to be found.  I don't know why this is the case and thus my question.

So the background:

SConstruct file -

> `doc_build_target = environment.Doxygen( "./configuration.dxc" )`
>   `environment.Alias( 'documentation', doc_build_target )`

The project structure uses a project specific `site_scons` directory

```
project
    site_scons
        site_tools
            doxygen
    SConstruct
    ...
```

The doxygen module has been retrieved per the instructions on the scons ToolIndex page (http://www.scons.org/wiki/ToolsIndex?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=site_init.py&titlesearch=Titles), from the https://bitbucket.org/russel/scons_doxygen site.

The exact command and scons response is as follows:

```
D:\project>scons documentation
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
**** Compiling in release mode...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
cd . && doxygen configuration.dxc
'doxygen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
scons: *** [stage\doc\html] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I have the doxygen application path in the system path environmental variable.  I've confirmed this by manually executing doxygen to build the documentation and everything works fine.  Furthermore, after manually generating the documentation - with HTML files now in existence - scons identifies that nothing needs to be done upon performing the above.

What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default scons environment not includes environment variables (such are system path variable). To do it you need add path variable to scons environment object.

You can find example [here](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x1750.html).

Also, more explaining you can found on scons man page if search by 'os.environ' keyword.

Comment: Thanks! It would explain perfectly my problem.  (I guess better to be wiser, and stupid looking, then just stupid looking!)